# Maven build succeeds without required depencency

Tags: java, maven, build, mvn-repo

I have a dependency com.somecompany.somelib in my maven module which is required.

I have classes in my source code which consume this dependency.

If I remove this dependency from my `classpath` in `intellij`, I see that my build for module fails in `intellij` (expected).

However this is not the case when I do `mvn clean install` on this module via the command line after removing the dependency from pom.xml. The build still succeeds where it should fail! (not expected)

I have checked with the `--debug` option enabled and I do not see the dependency being added. I see the class files being compiled and even the .class files in the resultant .jar file.

There is no occurrence of this dependency name in the `--debug` log.

I have spent a full day searching and reading but could not find any resolution/possible causes.

Below is some additional info if it helps.

`maven version - Apache maven 3.6.0`

`basedir = /home/user/git/repo/projectname/modulename`

`buildDirectory = /home/user/git/repo/projectname/modulename/target`

`compileSourceRoots = [/home/user/git/repo/projectname/modulename/src/main/java]`

`compilerId = javac`

`debug = true`

`encoding = UTF-8`

`failOnError = true`

`forceJavacCompilerUse = false`

`fork = false`

`optimize = false`

`source = 8`

`staleMillis = 0`

`target = 8`

`useIncrementalCompilation = true`

`verbose = false`

Comment: why should it fail? you have the dependency in your pom.xml, the library is not found on your local repo, so it is downloaded from the remote one

Comment: apologies, the build succeeds even after removing the dependency from pom.xml, I have edited it now.

Comment: the build succeeds after deleting the contents of .m2 folder as well.

Comment: have you checked your dependency tree? maybe it's already somewhere in the hierarchy

Comment: Double checked, I have also added the <exclusions> tag to avoid Transitive dependency.

Also, if it's being retrieved from the hierarchy, it should show up in the `debug` log as well correct?

Comment: have you tried mvn dependency:tree ?

Comment: @Stultuske Just did, the output is same as what I am seeing in the debug log, the removed dependency is not present but the build still succeeds.

Comment: Did you run the build outside IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes, from a terminal outside `intellij`